# Any similar function for fragment like onActivityResult()

Tags: android-fragments, fragment, android-lifecycle, onresume

In my application I have scenario like, 
When user click a button in FragmentA, it will show FragmentB. And when a button clicked on FragmentB it will go to FragmentC.

While navigating from A->B->C, I will set my activity title respectively as "A", "B" & "C".
This flow I did using,

```
public class FragmentC
   onCreateView(){
      mTxtHeaderTitle.setText(getString(R.string.fragC));
   } 
}
```

Now the question is, how I can set the title bar to "C" while user presses backkey and navigate back to B, ( C -> B )?

Is there any method callback available to do this?

```
onFragmentResult() as like onActivityResult() in Activity?
```

Please help.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get question properly.Did u mean that you want to set the title to "B" when the user switches to B from C by pressing backkey?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to display the title as "B" when I come back to FragmentB by pressing backkey in FragmentC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) callback method of Fragment to set the title.

onResume() is called by the system whenever the Fragment is in focus and interacting with the user.